# ImportError: cannot import name '_counter' from 'Crypto.Util'

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, cryptography, python-import

I am on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and using the Geanny editor with the python 3.7 interpreter.  I was trying to use AES 256 bit encryption.  I researched this problem all over the internet and tried various different solutions but to no avail.  The error I continue to get is

`ImportError: cannot import name '_counter' from 'Crypto.Util' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Util/__init__.py).`

Any suggestions or ideas of a solution to this problem?

Comment: You forgot to post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`sudo pip install pycrypto pycryptodomex`

If still not working:

`sudo pip uninstall pycrypto pycryptodomex`

`sudo pip install pycryptodome`

Note that pycrypto and pycryptodome will interfere with each other

> One must avoid having both PyCrypto and PyCryptodome installed at the
> same time, as they will interfere with each other.

([source](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html))